# Daylight Savings and sleep

Tags: sleep, dst

I have a C application that sleeps for 1 minute between tasks. How will this be affected when Daylight Savings Time ends? At 3:00am, when the clocks go back to 2:00am, will `sleep` suspend execution for 1 minute or 1 hour and 1 minute?

Example:

```
while(1)
{
   sleep(60);
   do_something();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your code will not be affected by the Daylight Savings Time ends . No problem.

When you use sleep function your program wait until a certain amount of time that you specify as parameter to the function, the time of the system doesn't affect the function behaviour.